# Google Drive Synced with Errors. On Ubuntu, can I recover my offline version of the file before it synced?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-chrome, linux

So I finished a bunch of work offline, and then I synced it... and it did not go well after:

[image]

It merged without deleting a bunch of parts as you can see there, and Page 7 is gone completely:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PYYbNGg.png]

The errors are just annoying, but losing that entire page is really frustrating. I want to see if I can find the old version still sitting on my computer. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try re-syncing your files?

Comment: How do you resync?

Comment: What do you used to sync your files?

Comment: Chromium. You connect to the internet, and it starts syncing. Google should really have a policy that before a sync of offline changes, they back up what you have on your computer. Seems like a dumb policy not to.

Answer (score -1):

I'll just add this as answer so you can see the picture.

If you have syncing issues then you can try this

1. Clicking the `google drive` in `task bar`
2. Click the `settings` (The 3 horizontal dots)
3. Then you can see something like `re-sync`

This is the picture of google drive if you don't have any syncing issues, but if you have one then it will show resync.

[image]

Comment: On ubuntu though?

Comment: Oh, so sorry. I didn't notice the linux tag. I'll revise my answer later.

Comment: Google Drive for PC is not available for Linux.